# How do I use "Mod" command for this program

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio

[image: http://i.imgur.com/l9J1z4L.png]

This is the program I need I'm trying to code for but I just don't know how to display the first digit and second digit.

```
Public Class Program

Private Sub btnDigit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDigit.Click
    Dim I As Decimal
    Dim digits As Decimal

    I = Val(Me.txtinput.Text)

    digits = 

    Me.lblanswerfirstdigit.Text =
    Me.lblanswerlastdigit.Text = 
End Sub
```

I tried my best, but I'm just not good at it yet.

Comment: What do want to do ? , why `MOD` ? if you only want to get the first and second digit.. you can use `LEFT` and `MID` function of vb.net

Comment: How would I do that then? I'm new to VB and I wouldn't know how to apply LEFT and MID function @JapzDivino

Comment: see my sample in the answer

Comment: Why is your label called "lastdigit" but the ui says second digit?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
lblanswerfirstdigit.Text = txtinput.Text.Chars(0) 'get the 1st char
lblanswerlastdigit.Text = txtinput.Text.Chars(1)  'get the 2nd char
```

A Try...Catch block (or a simpler If check) is recommended, to prevent errors in case of 1 digit numbers

Answer (score -2):

I think you don't need to use `MOD` , because that function is used to perform modulus division.

If you want to get the first, last or even in the middle. You can use `LEFT, RIGHT, and MID` function of vb.net

```
    LEFT(StringHere, LenghtHere)
    RIGHT(StringHere, LenghtHere)
    MID(StringHere, StarHere,LenghtHere)
```

something like:

```
    Me.lblanswerfirstdigit.Text = LEFT(Me.txtinput.Text, 1) 'get the first
    Me.lblanswerlastdigit.Text = RIGHT(Me.txtinput.Text, 1) 'get the last
```